# Trying to delete duplicate lines however getting "Not enough memory resources are available"

Tags: emeditor

I'm trying to use emeditor to delete duplicates in a 13gb file. 1 column, just newlines of text.

However, both tools to do this in emeditor (under edit->advanced) give me the same error of "Not enough memory resources are available".

Is there another way to do this? Any alternatives? Thanks

Comment: Get lines in array, sort, filter, write out new lines.

Comment: How many lines exist in your file, or what is the average length of a line?

Comment: 561,585,927 lines. Average length just guessing is probably around 20 chars.

Answer (score 1):

This prompt message means that available virtual memory is very low on your computer. How much physical memory do you have on your computer? I would recommend you to increase the physical memory size in your computer if possible. If that is not possible, please try:

1. Clean up your computer, and make sure you have enough space available in your hard drive where temporary files reside. The temporary folder can be set in the **Advanced** page of the **Customize** dialog box.
2. Close all apps, disable **Cortana** if not used, disable any startup apps if not used, restart Windows, and run only EmEditor.
3. Go to **Customize** on the **Tools** menu, select **Advanced**, select **1** from the **Number of Threads**.

[image]

4. If the prompt message still persists, you might need to check your Windows virtual memory settings. To check virtual memory settings, search for `performance` in the Windows Settings search box, select **Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows**, click the **Advanced** tab, click the **Change** button in the **Virtual memory** box.

If the **Automatically manage paging file size for all drives** was not set, try setting this automatic option first, restart Windows, and try again.

If this doesn't work or if the automatic option was already set, then clear the automatic option, try settings the Custom Size of `40960` MB for both **Initial size** and **Maximum size**, restart Windows and try again. I hope this works.

[image: Virtual Memory]

Comment: Hi Yutaka, I have 16GB of physical memory on my computer. Lots of available space on my harddrive too. The Threads suggestion hasnt worked either. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with virtual memory settings. Please try this.

Answer (score 1):

If not using a language
I would use Notepad++ and a simple

Find `(?m)^(?>(.*?\S.*)\R)(?=(?:.*\R)*?\1$)`
Replace nothing

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LJvs0g/1)

Removes dups from top down, its the fastest regex way to do it.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this but it didnt work. I ran it in emeditor and it couldnt find any matches in my document? I know there definitely is duplicates. Thanks

Comment: works with PCRE, Perl, Boost regex. Thinking should use NP++, whatever that editor is has some custom no-name regex engine. it works in other engines, yes ? yes https://regex101.com/r/LJvs0g/1

Comment: this regex special design to look and skip data in chunks of lines at a time. The alternative is to read all lines into an array and run a bubble sort. will take hours as well. better to divide whole into files of alpha start letters and single punctuation start. Use Perl open 26 new files, open 30Gig file, read line at a time, write to specific alpha file. when done it is ordered by alpha, just need to sort each file, remove dups, then join back together. You lose order this way but no more dups. The regex way i say preserves order but needs to act on data as a whole. So good luck on any